# Elasticsearch Mapping _parent

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my Question

```
PUT /test/child/1
{
  "test": 123
}

PUT /test/child/_mapping
{
  "child": {
    "_parent": {
      "type": "parent"
    }
  },
  "parent": {}
}
```

My child have document,can't add parent.

This is Error Message

```
"error": "MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[The _parent field's type option can't be changed]}]",
   "status": 400
```

If no document, it is work.

**I am sorry, I didn't say it clearly.
My question is how add parent in the child had document??**

Please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "parent": {},
      "child": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "parent"
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/parent/1
{
    "test_parent": 123
}

PUT /test_index/child/1?parent=1
{
  "test_child": 123
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/8efb91d986b43a294672471c49d39d98e78c0ffa